# Is there a way to limit the max size of a chart in chartjs whilst still maintaining responsiveness?

Tags: chart.js

I made a responsive doughnut in chartjs. On mobile devices the size fills out the screen nicely and is as I'd like it but when I switch to desktop it also fills out the entire screen and is too big for my liking. Is there a way to set the relative size to for example, half screen when viewing on desktop and then reverting to full-screen if being viewed on mobile?

I tried the different settings on the chartjs site but can't find anything helpful.

Comment: Have you tried "aspectRatio" option? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html

Comment: thanks.. yeah.. not really what I wanted.. in the end I just set the max size to the full size on a mobile device(eg. iphone 13)